# trimming a string plus checking if string is not empty

Tags: java, string

I have an array list in which objects are stored, and from those object's getters I get string value as shown below

```
List<abcd> hgfer = (List<abcd>)Getter.rows(jhfile);
            for(abcd f: hgfer)
            {           
            String p = f.getFromArea()
```

As shown above the array list and the values that I am extracting. Now I have to make sure that the string that I am getting is not empty plus it should be trimmed, I achieved this as shown below:

```
p.getFromArea().trim().length() > 0
```

Now there are several getters attached to this object which will return a string.
For every individual string I have to do this. I was thinking to make a separate individual method which will return a boolean value and a string parameter 
will be pass.For ex:

```
 private String validaterow(String g)
  {
  boolean valid = false;'
  try{
  **//code to check that should not be empty plus it should be trim one** 
  }
  catch(){}
  valid = false;  
  }
```

and I have to make a call to this method somewhere within the class

```
List<abcd> hgfer = (List<abcd>)Getter.rows(jhfile);
            for(abcd f: hgfer)
            {           
             if (!validaterow(f.getFromArea())
           {//customised message 
           }
           else
           continue;
```

**Now please advise how could I achieve that string should not be empty plus it
should be trim one**

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:-

```
public boolean isNullOrEmpty(String str) {
    return (str == null) || (str.trim().length() == 0);
}
```

This will return `true` if your `String` is `null` or `empty`, else `false`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#line.231), you could use theire method to check, if a string is empty or not.

```
/**
* <p>Checks if a String is whitespace, empty ("") or null.</p>
*
* <pre>
* StringUtils.isBlank(null)      = true
* StringUtils.isBlank("")        = true
* StringUtils.isBlank(" ")       = true
* StringUtils.isBlank("bob")     = false
* StringUtils.isBlank("  bob  ") = false
* </pre>
*
* @param str  the String to check, may be null
* @return <code>true</code> if the String is null, empty or whitespace
* @since 2.0
*/
public static boolean isBlank(String str) {
  int strLen;
  if (str == null || (strLen = str.length()) == 0) {
    return true;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
    if ((Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i)) == false)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

The reason for this way is demonstrated in this example:

```
System.out.println(Character.isWhitespace('c'));   // false
System.out.println(Character.isWhitespace(' '));   // true
System.out.println(Character.isWhitespace('\n'));  // true
System.out.println(Character.isWhitespace('\t'));  // true
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  private boolean validaterow(String text)
  {     
   try{
      return (text == null) || (text != null && text.trim().length() == 0);
    }
   catch(){}
      return false;  
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 boolean validateNullString(String str)
    {
        return (str == null || str.trim().length() == 0);

    }
```

This will validate your String object against null and empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private boolean validaterow(String g){
boolean isValid = false;
if(g.trim().isEmpty()){
    isValid = true;
}
return isValid;
```

}

If the parameter String is not empty the method will return false.

Answer (score 0):

Use StringUtils class from apache.commons.lang

```
 If (StringUtils.isNotBlank(yourString)){

      isValid = true;
 }
```

This will trim the yourString and check for null or blank value.